# How to correctly setup snapshots deeplearning4j

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, snapshot, deeplearning4j

I tried re-configuring my project for snapshots in intellij, please why is my [pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/54LiNKeR/2914b2d3c073c2f40a30d3b544c62c8f) not working according to the [documentation](https://deeplearning4j.org/docs/latest/deeplearning4j-config-snapshots)

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots-repo</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
        <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

> `<releases>..</releases>` and `<snapshots>..<snapshots/>` are outlined in red with a `Element 'releases' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.` error

Comment: turned out the IDE was the culprit, imported maven dependencies, download took a while everything is working now, the syntax error is still there but that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I took your snippet and tried to build the project locally.
I haven't seen such kind of error, everything in  tag looks valid.
The only thing that I have added to build you project is `<version>${nd4j.version}</version>` tag to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>${nd4j.backend}</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Could you please, make provided above changes and double check your `pom.xml` file syntax.

Comment: did you click the **pom.xml** link in the question, this is already there

Comment: Yes, I took your pom.xml from the link in the question.